# Converting Document fields before returning

Tags: rest, flask, document, mongoengine

I'm building a flask project with mongoengine, and I'm struggling to find a good way to convert some fields before returning a document.
I have this as a document:

```
class Effects(Document):
name = StringField(unique=True, required=True,
                   min_length=2, max_length=20, validation=name_is_not_taken)
parameters = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Parameter)
parameterKeys = ListField(StringField(required=True, null=True))
created_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
created_by = StringField(required=True)
effect_link = StringField(required=True)
description = StringField(required=False)
file = FileField(required=False)
```

When calling a route to get all of those documents (Effect.objects().all), here is what it looks like

```
{
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "62138365ae75aceb4c4f3466"
            },
            "created_at": {
                "$date": 1645449589917
            },
            "effect_link": "put link here",
            "name": "gain",
            "parameters": {
                "Gain": {
                    "default_value": 0.5,
                    "range_end": 1.0,
                    "range_start": 0.0,
                    "type": "range",
                    "unit": "float"
                }
            }
        },
```

My question is, is there a way to consistently convert the _id and created_at from objects to string everytime I return one or more Effects document so the result looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "62138365ae75aceb4c4f3466",
    "created_at": "62138365ae75aceb4c4f3466",
    "effect_link": "put link here",
    "name": "gain",
    "parameters": {
        "Gain": {
            "default_value": 0.5,
            "range_end": 1.0,
            "range_start": 0.0,
            "type": "range",
            "unit": "float"
        }
    }
}
```

I've seen that you can use aggregate in order to do operations like this but I'm not sure if it is the best way.
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken `mongoengine` does not supports serialization. I had few applications written in `mongoengine`. One of them used django so I was using [django-rest-framework-mongoengine](https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine), it may not be relevant to your project, because you are using `flask`. Alternative would be to use [mongoengine_serialize](https://github.com/aiscenblue/mongoengine_serialize), it only supports `ObjectIds` and `datetimes`, so I think it will be useful for your project.